# How to configure WordPress to handle 75,000 pages?

Tags: pages, memory, scale

I have a large site that's using WordPress.  We have 75,000 pages in the site so far, and it's performing well on the front-end.

The issue is that if anyone on our team touches the page editor (wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page), Apache eats up all the memory on the server.

I've tried disabling all plugins, but that didn't work.  I also tried debugging on our live server which a 4GB box... it still eats up all the memory and comes to a hault.

On this install, we also have 20,000 posts.  There's no issue loading those in wp-admin.  Maybe we should move all pages to posts - that's going to cause an issue with permalink structure, though.

Are there special settings or configurations I'm missing for a large WP site?

Comment: It's a known issue in wordpress, one of the tickets is http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/9864

Comment: @hakre that's true, thanks - looks like the issue is two years old and a fix won't be released soon.  Did you find an answer/fix yourself?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/cms-tree-page-view/
I use this plug-in for more than 55,000 entries hierarchical, works well

Answer (score 4):

The problem comes from the fact that, in order to display pages and their hierarchy, WP has to load all of them and then build the tree in memory.

So, you are saved if you can convert most of those pages into one or several non-hierarchical custom post types.

The permalink structure can be emulated.

Comment: Why is that? Can't it load just the number of pages requested by the currrent page (the one set in the screen options), then load their children, and exclude some from the end if needed to match that number? And the "parent" dropdown could be replaced with a simple search box (or keep the dropdown if # of pages doesn't exceed 100 or something)...

Comment: Thanks.  I'll need to research custom post types more. When they were first released, I remember you had to use a permalink structure like /cats/squiggles.  But maybe I can use just /squiggles for custom post types now (that's our permalink structure for these pages).  Hopefully it's a relatively easy fix!

Comment: @One Trick Pony: Because the number of db queries would grow exponentially.

Comment: Is this problem going to happen with the new bbpress forum plugin? I've been wanting to convert my vb forums (1.2million threads) to bbpress, and reading this is causing me to seriously doubt that I can do it

Comment: @shawn: bbPress doesn't use pages. It uses non-hierarchical post types + a hierarchical taxonomy.

Comment: @scribu thanks again for the help.  You mentioned the permalink structure can be emulated.  I did some hunting and can't find a solution for setting up the permalinks like this:
mysite.com/my-custom-post

 - this is how we currently have them setup as pages.  Looking at custom post types, it looks like I have to use this permalink structure:
mysite.com/custom-type/my-custom-post - do you by any chance know if it's possible to remove the custom-type slug?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has been asked before on this site. If not, please create a separate question and link to it from here.